# Как в gulp сборке не минифицировать js файл в build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

Мне нужно чтобы в production ( npm run build ) НЕ минифицировать основной js файл ( app.js ).
В этой сборке используется webpack-stream для сжатия и экспорта других файлов/библиотек в единый js файл. Но мне, по некоторым причинам, нужен обычный читаемый js файл, такой же как и в режиме development, только с импортированными в него файлами ( если такие имеются ).

**JS.JS:**

```
import webpack from "webpack-stream";

export const js = () => {
  return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.js, { sourcemaps: app.isDev })
    .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
      app.plugins.notify.onError({
        title: "JS",
        message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
      }))
    )
    .pipe(webpack({
      mode: app.isBuild ? 'production' : 'development',
      output: {
        filename: 'app.min.js',
      }
    }))
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.js))
    .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream());
}
```

**JS.JS (после некоторых изменений):**

```
import webpack from "webpack-stream";

export const js = () => {
    return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.js, { sourcemaps: app.isDev })
        .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
            app.plugins.notify.onError({
                title: "JS",
                message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
            }))
        )
        .pipe(webpack({
            mode: 'development',
            optimization: {
                minimize: false
            },
            output: {
                filename: 'app.js',
            },
            resolve: {
                modules: [
                    'node_modules'
                ]
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
                    }
                ]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.js))
        .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream());
}
```

**APP.JS:**

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "./src/js/app.js":
/*!***********************!*\
  !*** ./src/js/app.js ***!
  \***********************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack___webpack_module__, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__); ...
```

Я попытался настроить **webpack**, чтобы он не сжимал файл с помощью `minimaze: false`, также изменил **mode**, добавил модуль **babel-loader**, но ничего не вышло.

Если нужна дополнительная информация, дайте знать, спасибо заранее !

P.S. Сборка от [Фрилансер По Жизни](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU88mLuLWlk&t=3795s)

Comment: Попробуйте в файл конфига вебпака добавить "devtool": "source-map"

Comment: @Elmir У меня нету webpack.config.js это gulp сборка, я могу настроить webpack только через файл js.js, но как именно, я как раз пытаюсь узнать